# Data frame restructure in R from wide format to two columns

Tags: r, data-structures, tidyverse, dataformat

I am working on a data set that has 4 columns that represent when a certain forest patch was cut.

Three of these columns represent a year with each row representing a month. e.g. Column: 2015, Row: 1 = January, 2015

The last column is a unique ID for each site.

For my analysis, I need to restructure this data so that it is 2 rows, the site, and a date format for the cut. As we do not know the exact day we have chosen the 15th of each month as a proxy.

I have attached photos of the data and a summary.

[image]

[image]

The final outcome I would like is like so

```
uniqueid <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
cut <- as.Date(c('2015-1-15','2016-3-15','2017-3-15'))
stack_example <- data.frame(uniqueid, cut)
```

Could somebody please help me to restructure the data so it is like the example output?

[image]

Thank you very much

<<<< EDIT FOR AKRUN >>>>>

```
 dput(head(clf))
```

> structure(list(X2017 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
> NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), X2016 = c(NA_integer_,
> NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_ ),
> X2015 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
> NA_integer_, NA_integer_), idunique = 1:6), row.names = c(NA,  6L),
> class = "data.frame")

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of small data so that I can get the structure.  i.e. `dput(head(yourdata))`

Comment: Updated in the question so you can view easier, at the bottom. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate the effort.

Comment: Sorry, it was a simple typo - I used `idunique` at one place, and then `uniqueid` at another.  Updated. please test it now

Comment: I think when I looked at your expected, it showed `uniqueid` and somehow, I copied that name instead of the original

Comment: No worries at all, appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pivot to long format with `pivot_longer` and then use `paste` or `str_c` or `sprintf`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
clf %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = -idunique, values_drop_na = TRUE,
           names_to = 'date', values_to = 'value') %>%
      transmute(idunique, cut = sprintf('%s-%02d-15', 
               str_remove(date, '^X'), value))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  idunique cut       
#     <int> <chr>     
#1        3 2017-03-15
```

#### data

```
# OP's dput showed all rows NA.  So, added a value for test
clf$X2017[3] <- 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am getting this error message, Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 151902.
i Input `..1` is `uniqueid`.
i Input `..1` must be size 151902 or 1, not 3.

Comment: Edited the comment there!

Comment: @KilianMurphy Does the `df1 %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = -idunique, values_drop_na = TRUE,
           names_to = 'date', values_to = 'value')` line works without any error

Comment: Yep that works, creates a tibble! I changed df1 to the name of the dataframe obviously but that line works.

Comment: Output from the first line: A tibble: 151,902 x 5
   X2017 X2016 X2015 date     value
   <int> <int> <int> <chr>    <int>
 1    NA    NA    NA idunique     1

Comment: @KilianMurphy that is not possible.  Do you have a column name `idunique` or is it `uniqueid`.  The `pivot_longer`, I specified `cols` to reshape from wide to long as all the other columns except 'idunique`

Comment: Yes, see the photo of the dataframe attached in the question please, 4 columns, 3 years and idunique.